# Activation link activates by itself at mail reception

Tags: php, email, gmail

I'm trying to make a simple activation token and I'm having an issue.
Here is my verification code :

```
if (isset($_GET['token'], $_GET['account_id']) && !empty($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['account_id']))
{
    // Checking if the account has a token to activate
    if ($query[0] > 0)
    {
        // Fetching some info about the token
        if ($tokenData['used'] == 0)
        {
            if ($tokenData['token'] == $_GET['token']) // Checking if given token is valid
            {
                // Activates user account
                // Sets the token as 'used'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the screenshot of the table structure:

[image: Screenshot of the table structure]

Here is what happens :
When I try to create a test account (myaddress@gmail.com) everything works, the account and tokens are created. The token is not used and the account is not activated.
But after I receive the mail, less than a second after I receive it, the token is set to used and the account activated so something must have clicked the link even tho I didn't.

I would like to know if there's a way to ensure that it's the actual user that clicked the link and not the email client checking if the link is secure or something.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: hard to say; what does an "example" GET url look like? You also don't need `isset($_GET['token'], $_GET['account_id']) &&` since `empty()` checks for both at the same time.

Comment: you can't. if something is pre-fetching the links (e.g. a virus scanner), there's no way to tell between that hit and the user legitimately clicking on the link. Both requests would theoretically be identical, especially if the virus scanner (or whatever's "clicking") disguises its user agent.

Comment: you could have them paste a special code in another input/form along with a checkbox for them to check

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't knew that, thanks !

Comment: @MarcB I think I'll add a button or a simple form to validate it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Here's what it looks like : login.php?account_id=12&token=0c8f1fc6e94cf3385eaf610b9fa3b3b2

Comment: I would add another condition to this. I.e.: `if ($tokenData['token'] == $_GET['token'] && $_GET['account_id'] == '12')` yet using another page to enter a special code with a checkbox. Bots or email clients can't check those. Yet, encoding an email would also help along with a one-time token set to self-destruct.